# PHP behaving strange in for loop with associative array

Tags: php

the attached image is self-explanatory. I think its not new, but i'd like to understand the details behind it.
So to summarize my problem, when an associative array, that has only string keys, is passed to a basic for loop, it overflows, when i assign a value to one of its - previously non existant - indexed keys.
Why is that? (The image if from tehplayground php sandbox, but does the same on local machine @ PHP 7.3.2
[PHP sandbox run img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEqbB.jpg)

```
$result = array('key' => 'value1',
                'key2' => 'value2' );     

echo "size of result=".count($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
  echo "i=".$i.", result[".$i."]=".$result[$i]."\n";
  $result[$i] = "e";
}

//output:
i=0, result[0]=
i=1, result[1]=
i=2, result[2]=
i=3, result[3]=
i=4, result[4]=
i=5, result[5]=
i=6, result[6]=
i=7, result[7]=
i=8, result[8]=
i=9, result[9]=
i=10, result[10]=
i=11, result[11]=
// The printout continues infinitely...
```

Comment: Please post code and other things in your post instead of linking to an image. This happens because the condition is executed after each loop run and you are adding elements to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this if you want to run loop based on before everything count:

```
$result_count = count($result);
for ($i =0; $i<$result_count; $i++){
```

Comment: Yes, it was the fix, but for first: this whole thing looked rather strange. Thanks, i upvote this answer.